# Select column numbers only from table in R

Tags: r

I am new using R, and I have a problem when reading data.
I am reading a .csv file:

```
table<- read.table("/Users/.../data.plants.csv", header=FALSE, sep=";")
```

The table has the format:

```
      V1              V2                    V3         V4         V5     V6        V7        V8
```

1   nutrient           light microsatellite_length genotype_A genotype_B height leaf_type leaf_size

2       rich          bright                     4         AA         Bb   48.5     rough     10.43

3       rich          bright                     2         Aa         Bb     47    smooth      6.54

....(continues)

I want to just select one column, the column that has leaf size.
I am doing it like this:

```
x<-subset(table,select=c(V8))
```

It has a problem, it also selects the header ("leaf_size") and I want just the numeric values.
How can I select just the column numeric values?

Comment: Use `header=TRUE` in your `read.table` call. Or just use `read.csv` as it defaults to this.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer then, so people can see that its solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use `header=TRUE` in your `read.table` call. Or just use `read.csv` as it defaults to this.

```
plants <- read.csv("/Users/.../data.plants.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the first answer, by default, read.csv results in strings being classified as factors. If you do not want this (and generally, you don't), one uses:

```
read.table('plants.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=';') -> plants
plants[,6]
```

will then give you the sixth column as strings. I'll assume you want it as numbers, given by `as.numeric(plants[,6])`. Hope that helps!